# Replacement for std::rel_ops in c++20

Tags: c++, comparison-operators, c++20

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/rel_ops/operator_cmp) `std::rel_ops` operators are marked as deprecated since C++20.

> [image: deprecated]

What should be used instead since C++20?

Comment: Wow, you're programming already for C++23? Any jobs going at your place?

Comment: Deprecated doesn't necessarily mean "going away". There are other parts of the standard that has already been deprecated for 20 years.

Comment: @BoPersson yep, I know, but I prefer not to use deprecated things before they become removed completely from the implementations.

Comment: @Bathsheba if you have a 10+ years of experience with C++20 you are welcome.

Comment: @alexolut: In which case I already know if you hired me.